# Use Find Method to Format Certain String in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range that contains several instances of the string "freq!" randomly scattered throughout. I want to change the font of these strings to red. I tried using the Find method with no luck:

```
[D1:H5000].Find(What:=”freq!”, LookIn:=xlValues).Font.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your `.Find` isn't working is because it's only designed to find one instance. To find multiple instances, you need to also use `.FindNext` within a loop. See the example below:

Note the use of wildcards around the search string.

```
Sub ChangeFontColor()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rr As Range
Dim sAdd As String
Dim sStr As String

sStr = "*freq!*"

With Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("D1:H5000")
    Set rng = .Find(sStr)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        sAdd = rng.Address
        Do
            If rr Is Nothing Then
                Set rr = rng
            Else
                Set rr = Application.Union(rr, rng)
            End If
            Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
        Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> sAdd
    End If
End With

If Not rr Is Nothing Then
    rr.Font.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
End If

End Sub
```

This example should execute pretty quickly depending on how many instances there are. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) for more information on `.FindNext`.

Comment: Ah, this is my first time using Find, and thought it was the magic bullet for avoiding loops. did not realize it only finds one instance. What a rip. Your code does not work for me even after I renamed the Worksheets(2).Range("D1:H5000") to match my own worksheet name. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Is it due to the fact that I didn't include wildcards around the search string? Please see my edited answer. BTW, I use `.Find` all the time to avoid using loops. One just needs to know its limitations. :)

Comment: + 1 Good one :) [ANOTHER LINK](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) Also to make your code faster, instead of coloring the cells in a loop, you can create one range using `Union` and the color all the cells in one go after the loop.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I love the suggestion! Thanks! I've updated my code to include your suggestion.

Comment: @ARich, unfortunately, your wildcards made no difference. The code runs, but the font of the "freq!" strings do not change to red.

Comment: I've tested the code on a sample dataset, and it works for me. Are you sure that the `D1:H5000` range is correct?

Comment: @ARich: Your code just colors the font of the entire cell :) I think what the user wants is to color only one particular word which has `freq!` For that, you need to use `.Characters(Start:=X, Length:=Y).Font`. You will have to loop through each cell  in `rr` and then find the start/end positions of that word and then color it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Perhaps. But the OP said that Gary's code worked, which leads me to think that `freq!` is the entire cell's contents. :) Max, could you clarify for us, please?

Comment: He did clarify. See his last comment

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub BetterRedThan()
    Dim rFound As Range, rBig As Range, r As Range
    Set rFound = Nothing
    Set rBig = Range("D1:H5000")
    For Each r In rBig
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "freq!") > 0 Then
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Set rFound = r
            Else
                Set rFound = Union(r, rFound)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If rFound Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rFound.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works, thanks, but I was hoping to avoid the loop by using the Find method. Can the loop not be avoided?

Comment: Hi Max:   You could use **Find** , but probably still need to loop.

Comment: + 1 on using Union :) Almost(not completely) compensates for the for each loop. :)

Comment: Gary, I think I misunderstood what OP wants :) See my last comment under @ARich post.